# IIS 7.5 and ColdFusion 9.0.1 Compatibility Issue

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion-9

need some help... I have Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit) IIS 7.5 running ASP.net sites in Classic Mode. I have ColdFusion 9.0.1 (64 bit) installed. My CF sites work fine in integrated mode with .net 4.0.
My .Net sites (3.5 and 4.0) will not work in Integrated mode only classic Mode. 
I am trying to get all my .Net sites to run in Integrated Mode.
I recently upgraded to CF 9.0.1 from 9.0.0

I get this error from a .Net site set to Integrated Mode:

```
HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
Detailed Error Information
Module: ConfigurationValidationModule
Notification: BeginRequest
Handler: AboMapperCustom-89651247
Error Code: 0x80070032
Requested URL http://www.mysite.com:80/
Physical Path D:\www\mysite.com
Logon Method Not yet determined
Logon User Not yet determined
```

Thanks In Advance!!!

I am going to try this to solve the issue... this is from the Adobe 9.0.1 Update installation PDF.
Unconfigure the (already configured) websites.
Turn off all options under IIS 6 Management Compatibility 
Reconfigure the websites.
From all the research I have done, this points to the issue; (IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility installed).

Comment: This question shoud probably be moved to http://serverfault.com.